# Run multiple docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using an application which runs on 3 different docker images:

- The first one is the server HTTP callable with a REST API
- The second one is rabbitmq
- The third one is a worker

The whole application is launched with `docker-compose up`

Really simple :)

I would like to make it scalable and run multiple instances of this entire application (the 3 docker images) independently of the others, and then put a load balancer like `haproxy` which will redirect to one of the applications.

I saw that I can use `docker-compose up --scale blablabla` however the problem with this is that I can scale containers, but I really want to keep the different "applications" independent.

For example if I want 3 versions of the app I will have 9 docker images etc.

I saw that we can run docker inside docker with `--privilege` (allowing me to create one docker with the 3 dockers inside) but I read on Stack Overflow that it is not a suitable solution.

Do you have a solution? Or at least some documents to read.

I heard that Kubernetes could be a solution but I am not sure. I read (on Stack):

> If you need multiple containers tightly bound, you may want to look at Kubernetes that runs docker inside their "pods"

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It sounds like you just want 3 different environments or "stacks" of your Compose application running independently of each other. If this is the case, you can handle this with the `--project-name` or `-p` option to `docker-compose`. An example would be something like this:

- Launch application version 1: `docker-compose -p appv1 up -d`
- Launch application version 2: `docker-compose -p appv2 up -d`
- Launch application version 3: `docker-compose -p appv3 up -d`

At this point, you would have 3 different sets of containers running that can scale independently of each other. Docker Compose will prepend the project name (which is usually inferred from the folder name) to the container names. You will end up with container names such as `appv1_worker_1`, `appv2_worker_1`, `appv3_worker1`. If you were to scale only `appv2` worker service (`docker-compose -p appv2 scale worker=2`) you would then get an additional `appv2_worker_2`.

By default, compose always creates a default network that the containers can talk inside of. In this case, you would have 3 independent networks (`appv1_default`, `appv2_default`, and `appv3_default`).

If you next wanted to run different images for each project name, you could use environment variable interpolation in the `docker-compose.yml`. For example, you could specify `image: ${MYIMAGE}` for a service and then do something such as:

- `MYIMAGE=myorg/myapp:v1 docker-compose -p appv1 up -d`
- `MYIMAGE=myorg/myapp:v2 docker-compose -p appv2 up -d`

Hope this is helpful as an idea to do it inside of Docker Compose.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. Just a last question. As I will have 3 differents http handler. Do you maybe know how I can set a load balancer (like haproxy or something else) to dispatch between the 3.

Comment: There are many examples of that around. One is https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy. Another using docker-gen is https://github.com/indiehosters/haproxy/blob/master/docker-compose.yml. Basically, you can run HAProxy as a service and link it to your application. Just as each project will have its own network, each will have its own HAProxy as well. Though, if you want to run multiple on the same host and publish a port, you probably will have to make a `${PORT}` environment variable and set a different port for each stack as well (just like the image).

Comment: Perfect thanks. I think I will go to the environmenr variable. Ifound a nice tutorial. I will try. Thank you for your time

Comment: Is there an equivalent for running `docker-compose run app <cmd>`?

Comment: I wouldn't think it is different than the others. Use `-p` to set the particular project and then the service and command: `docker-compose -p appv2 run myservice echo "hello"`

Comment: How to properly stop service run with `-p` option? When I'm trying to run `docker-compose -p appv1 -f somedir/docker-compose.yml --project-directory . down` I get error: `yaml: line 20: did not find expected key`.

Comment: @Taz that probably warrants a new question. It sounds like en error in the YAML.

Comment: Are the volumes shared or separate as well?

Comment: if I use `container_name:mysql` in docker-compose.yml and use it for BE code to connect as `mysql_host: mysql` would it still work? or project name will be added to the internal container name as well and become `appv1_mysql` inside?

Comment: answering my question above, I should remove `container_name:mysql` and let it generate a name prefixed with the project name, but I can use `hostname: mysql` to keep same hostname I used inside network.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to run multiple docker-compose files at once from a single command, use this method.
If the compose files are docker-compose1.yml and docker-compose2.yml, you can run both docker files using,

docker-compose -f docker-compose1.yml -f  docker-compose2.yml up

Comment: This method is the same as if you copy and pasted the services into the same docker-compose file. If, for example, you have two services named `app`, then the result of running this would be a single stack with one `app` container that had a mixture of configuration from both compose files.

Comment: @RyanPatterson that is not true. In my case I have docker-compose files of varying docker-compose versions that I'm able to start up using the `docker-compose -f file1 -f file2 ...` style command. Merging the services into 1 compose file will not simply work if you `copy and paste` as there are differences in the yml syntax. It takes a lot of effort if you're trying to switch from docker compose 2.x to something in 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.env` file. There you must set a COMPOSE_FILE environment variable and set it to `COMPOSE_FILE=a.yaml:b.yaml:c.yaml`

Now you can run all compose files with `docker-compose up`

```
projekt/
    .env
    a.yaml
    b.yaml
    c.yaml
```