# How to make multiple duplicate container for an php application which is using mysql database along with phpmyadmin with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a php application ( penetration labs) running on mysql db and it uses phpmyadmin. Now I want to make 30 instances of it with docker to assign it to 30 people for practice. I want each one of them with separate web application and unique database so that nobody can interfere with their testing.

This is my docker-compose file. Application is working fine on port 8081 (PMA) but I am facing issue on port 8082

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  php1:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db:3306
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=vehicle_insurance
      - MY_USER=root
      - MY_PASSWORD=root
    depends_on:
      - db
      - phpmyadmin1
    volumes:
      - "./qApiLabs/:/var/www/html"

  php2:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8002:80"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db1:3307
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=vehicle_insurance
      - MY_USER=root
      - MY_PASSWORD=root
    depends_on:
      - db1
      - phpmyadmin2
    volumes:
      - "./qApiLabs/:/var/www/html"

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=vehicle_insurance
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - "./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"

  db1:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=vehicle_insurance
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
    volumes:
      - "./db1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"

  phpmyadmin1:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db:3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

  phpmyadmin2:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db1:3307
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
```

Comment: I want separate db for each application, but this solutions uses same db for each instance

Comment: Does [this answer](/a/78044094) work for you?  Or more generally [Run multiple docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957259/run-multiple-docker-compose)?